# Python progressbar visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, progress-bar, tqdm

I was wondering how I could get progressbars within Visual Studio Code that look like the ones below. Currently I am using tqdm to track the progress of my scripts but I want my progress bars to look like the defaults ones from visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: do you mean print the bar on the terminal while your python software is working?

Comment: @NicoCaldo, yess. So before I was using tqdm to track the progress of my own scripts but I think this progress bar looks much neater

Comment: it just uses a different character, can't you configure tqdm to use a box draw character